# GMaps.js setContextMenu

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps.js

I have managed to add a context menu to a map using GMaps.js as per their example below

```
map.setContextMenu({
  control: 'map',
    options: [{
        title: 'Add marker',
        name: 'add_marker',
        action: function(e) {
            this.addMarker({
              lat: e.latLng.lat(),
              lng: e.latLng.lng(),
              title: 'New marker'
            });
        }
    }, {
        title: 'Center here',
        name: 'center_here',
        action: function(e) {
        this.setCenter(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());
    }
  }]
});
```

However I cannot seem to add a context menu to a marker.

Could someone post how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code work perfect for me, also if you can't see the contextMenu maybe you should try with right click it shows up the menu !!

```
map.setContextMenu({
        control: 'map',
        options: [{
            title: 'Add marker',
            name: 'add_marker',
            action: function(e){
                this.addMarker({
                    lat: e.latLng.lat(),
                    lng: e.latLng.lng(),
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    draggable:true,
                    title: 'New Marker'
                });
                this.hideContextMenu();
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Center here',
            name: 'center_here',
            action: function(e){
                this.setCenter(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());
            }
        }]
    });
    map.setContextMenu({
        control: 'marker',
        options: [{
            title: 'Center here',
            name: 'center_here',
            action: function(e){
                this.setCenter(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());
            }
        }]
    });
```

[image: Right click on map with gmaps]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean an infoWindow as demoed here? http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/examples/markers.html

If you look at the source for that page, you'll see you just need to add

```
infoWindow: {
    content: '<p>HTML Content</p>'
}
```

to your addMarker bit, ie. below the title. It's real easy! :)

Comment: No, I mean by using the same API (setContextMenu) as above but on a marker rather than the map. I am not sure how it is done. It says you can add a menu to a marker by using control:marker but this did nothing. Any ideas